# Pass user-agent information to the angular universal framework

Tags: angular, angular-universal

How to extend the angular universal server with the [express-useragent](https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent) middleware and provide details from request header within angular framework such as:

```
{
  "isMobile":false,
  "isDesktop":true,
  "isBot":false,
  .....
  "browser":"Chrome",
  "version":"17.0.963.79",
  "os":"Windows 7",
  "platform":"Microsoft Windows",
  "source":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79..."
}
```

If using angular framework:

```
@angular/cli                    16.0.6
@nguniversal/builders           16.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     16.1.1
@schematics/angular             16.0.6
```

how to setup server.ts to provide useragent information like "isMobile" within the angular framework so that I can access this information before server side rendering process begins? Can I just `import * as useragent from 'express-useragent';` and modify app function to pass those information as variable to rendering process?

```
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  server.use(useragent.express());
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    //req.useragent
    ...
  });
```

At the end I would like to resolve the variable "isMobile" e.g. in the app-routing.modules.ts file.

Comment: ASP.NET Core deals with this differently, and requires you to have a custom `main.server.ts`. Since (in my case) the angular app is hosted through my backend, I'm able to pass information (request headers, etc) to my angular app [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/Demo/Demo.Web/Services/DemoSpaPrerenderingService.cs#L41). But it depends on what backend stack you're using...

Comment: I've written an article [here](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-ssr-under-the-hood-asp-net-core-51562b70e511) about how SSR works in this serup, and why it requires you to modify the `main.server.ts` in order to pass data to the angular app during SSR